# Multer doesn't create file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I have a problem with file creation with multer.

File architecture:

```
My app folder
   Back
      config
        -config.json
      images
      middleware
        -auth.js
        -multer-config.js
      migrations
        -create-user.js
        -create-message.js
      models
        -index.js
        -message.js
        -user.js
      node_modules
      routes
        -posts.js
        -users.js
      -.env
      -app.js
      -server.js
      -package.json
      -package-lock.json

   Front
      --some files
```

Front:

```
async handleSubmit() {

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', this.file[0]);

    await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/sendTest",{
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    headers:{"content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=image", "authorization": this.$store.state.jwt}
    });

}
```

Back (/back/routes/posts.js):

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
var models = require('../models');
const auth = require('../middleware/auth');
const multer = require('../middleware/multer-config');

router.post('/sendTest', auth, multer, async (req, res, next) => {
    try {

        console.log(req.file); // return undefined

        res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Message publié'
        });

    } catch (err) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: err.original.sqlMessage });
    }

});
```

Back (/back/app.js):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const helmet = require('helmet'); 
const path = require('path');
app.use(helmet()); 

// Routage
const postsRoutes = require("./routes/posts");
const usersRoutes = require("./routes/users");

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); 
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization'); 
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
    next();
});

app.use(express.json());

app.use('/api', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));
app.use('/api', postsRoutes);
app.use('/api', usersRoutes);

module.exports = app;
```

multer-config:

```
const multer = require('multer');

const MIME_TYPES = {
  'image/jpg': 'jpg',
  'image/jpeg': 'jpg',
  'image/png': 'png',
  'image/gif': 'gif'
};

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, callback) => {
    callback(null, 'images');
  },
  filename: (req, file, callback) => {
    const name = file.originalname.split(' ').join('_');
    const extension = MIME_TYPES[file.mimetype];
    callback(null, name + Date.now() + '.' + extension);
  }
});

module.exports = multer({storage: storage}).single('images');
```

console.log(this.file[0]) from front returns :

```
File { name: "Screenshot_2.jpg", lastModified: 1635463756273, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 117741, type: "image/jpeg" }
```

console.log(formData) from front returns :

```
FormData {  }
```

But, that's normal, we have to use keys:

```
for (var [key, value] of formData.entries()) { 
  console.log(key, value);
}
```

returns

```
image 
File { name: "Screenshot_2.jpg", lastModified: 1635463756273, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 117741, type: "image/jpeg" }
```

[We can see the request in Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVV9C.png)

I think the file format sent from Front is therefore good.

As i understand multer has to create the file in "/back/images" and then we should be able to use req.file in the route "/sendTest" but it returns undefined.

I'm using sequelize to connect to database.

I'm not sure if multer is called after "auth" because a console.log("test") in multer-config should display in the console "test" when I send my request, nothing appears in the console, except when I save the "multer-config" file after a change.

If anyone has an idea of how to fix the problem or sees an error somewhere, I'm interested!

Comment: File is uploading with Postman then the problem seems to come from frontend but I don't see the mistake with formData

Answer (score 0):

I found errors:

Back (/back/app.js):
replace

```
app.use('/api', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));
```

by

```
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));
```

Front:
Remove headers content-type:

```
    await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/sendTest",{
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    headers:{"authorization": this.$store.state.jwt}
    });
```

Then now files are uploaded !

Hope it be useful for you :)